# Spring integration: an aggregator that can release when all messages are processed

Tags: spring-integration

I am building a system that call many and diffrent web service and i wish to generate a report about all errors returned after calling ws.

For that, I use an `<int:aggregator: >` to aggregate messages from `error-channel`  but i can't know the `release-strategy` because , i like to aggregate all messages of error-channel. so how can i configure `<int:aggregator >` to aggregate all messages.

```
<int:aggregator 
    correlation-strategy-expression="'${error.msg.correlation.key}'" 
    input-channel="ws.rsp.error.channel"
    output-channel="outboundMailChannel"
     ref="errorAggregator"
     method="generateErrorReport"
    release-strategy-expression="false" 
    group-timeout="2000"
```

expire-groups-upon-completion="true"/>

```
<int:service-activator
    input-channel="outboundMailChannel"
     ref="errorMsgAgregatedActivator"
         method="handleMessage"
/>
```

And the activator:

```
@ServiceActivator
public void handleMessage(Message<Collection<Object>> errorList) {

    Collection<Object> payload=errorList.getPayload();
   System.out.println("error list: "+payload.toString());
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation either needs an appropriate release strategy, or you can simply use `release-strategy-expression="false"` (never release), and use a `group-timeout` to release whatever's in the group after some time.

You may want to use a constant correlation `correlation-strategy-expresision="'foo'"` and set `expire-groups-upon-completion="true"` so a new group starts with the next message.

Comment: but i can't predict the time out , because i some error  messages arrived after time-out and thus, it can be lost

Comment: They won't be lost, a new group will be started and released later. As I said - you need some criteria on which to decide to release the group; this either can be based on the group content (messages) or a time.

Comment: For me the premise to use an `aggregator` for this kind of tasks smells not good. If you are going to do reporting you should take a look to some `store` solution from where you can iterate data and/or filter and build some cuts. The `List` is the simplest such a store...

Comment: I have added a `discard-channel`, i notice that all mesages go to `discard-channel`

Comment: I resolved it by adding `send-partial-result-on-expiry="true"` which send the aggregator result to the output-channel, but not discard-channel on expire.